# How to keep the current number count after browser refresh using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

This number counter is running continuously until it will reach in the certain number. The value "from" is from the mysql db and in every 4 seconds the number will be add 1. But this added number is a dummy  only and it will not save in the database.

I'm trying to keep the current number count after reloading the browser page using localStorage but I have no luck to store it. I want to save the number while counting in a localStorage in a specific time only, e.g. from 9am to 7pm everyday.

**EDIT:** there's a way that, the counter is continuous adding in every 4 seconds even there's no user viewing the page? So the value of number counter is sync... in every devices

Can please you help to achieve this? What is the better way to sync the value in different device browser? JS Cookies or localStorage? [Live link](https://codepen.io/defotograf/pen/mmwazm)

```
var curr_date        = new Date();
var current_time     = curr_date.getTime()/1000;
var current_hour     = curr_date.getHours();
var current_minutes  = curr_date.getMinutes();
var current_seconds  = curr_date.getSeconds();
var curr_time        = current_hour + ":" + current_minutes + ":" + current_seconds;
//var initial_time = 1492681140 //1488333600; //1488326400
var initial_time     = curr_date.getTime()/1000;
var target_time      = 1512136800; //1498917600; //1498860000
var speed            = 60*60*24*12*30*7*2;
var current_data     = 800000 + (current_time - initial_time)/(target_time - initial_time) * 250000;

switch((new Date).getTime()){
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
}

(function($){
    $.fn.countTo = function (options){
        options = options || {};

        return $(this).each(function (){
            //set options for current element
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults,{
                from: $(this).data('from'),
                to: $(this).data('to'),
                speed: $(this).data('speed'),
                refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
                decimals: $(this).data('decimals')
            }, options);

            var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
            increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops; //how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update

            //references & variables that will change with each update
            var self = this,
                $self = $(this),
                loopCount = 0,
                value = settings.from,
                data = $self.data('countTo') || {};
                $self.data('countTo', data);

            //if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
            if (data.interval){
                clearInterval(data.interval);
            }

            data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);
            render(value); 

            function updateTimer(){
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                render(value);
                  if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function'){
                    settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
                  }

                if (loopCount >= loops){
                    //remove the interval
                    $self.removeData('countTo');
                    clearInterval(data.interval);
                    value = settings.to;

                    if(typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function'){
                        settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            function render(value){
                var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
                $self.html(formattedValue);
                $self.html(value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' '));
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults ={
        from: 0,               
        to: 0,                 
        speed: 400,            
        refreshInterval: 1000,  
        decimals: 0,           
        formatter: formatter,  
        onUpdate: null,       
        onComplete: null       
    };

    function formatter(value, settings){
        return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
    }

    //custom formatting example
    $('.count-number').data('countToOptions',{
        formatter: function (value, options){
           return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        }
    });

    $('.timer').each(count); //start all the timers
    function count(options){
        var $this = $(this);
        options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || {});
        $this.countTo(options);
    }

    if(curr_time >= '10:00:00' && curr_time <= '22:00:00'){
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: current_data,
            to: 1000000,                         
            speed: speed,
            refreshInterval: 1000,
            onUpdate: function(value){
                console.debug(this);
            },
            onComplete: function(value){
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    } else if(curr_time >= '22:00:01' && curr_time <= '9:59:59'){
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 800000,
            to: 800000
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any `localstorage` code, but what you want to do is, when the page loads again, instead of starting `current_data` from 800000 +....., check if the `localstorage` value is available and use that instead.

Update the implementation like so

```
var current_data = 0;

if (localStorage.getItem("myCounterValue") != undefined) {
  current_data = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("myCounterValue"));
} else {
  current_data =
    800000 +
    (current_time - initial_time) / (target_time - initial_time) * 250000;
}
```

Set the storage value inside your `update` routine

```
$(".timer").countTo({
    from: current_data,
    to: 1000000,
    speed: speed,
    refreshInterval: 1000,
    onUpdate: function (value) {
        //console.debug(value);
        localStorage.setItem("myCounterValue", value);
    },
    onComplete: function (value) {
        console.debug(this);
    }
});
```

This should save and load the last count.Let us know.

Comment: there's a way that, the counter is continuos adding in every 4 seconds even there's no user viewing the page? So the value of number counter is sync... in every devices.

Comment: @Deegee, unfortunately, the setup does not give you that ability. you should be able to do bit of math and may be achieve that. by saving the time when it was last `updated` and then when they comeback to the page check the time difference and calculate total no.of 4 secs passed and increment the count...